# Spring Data JPA and Projection getting ConverterNotFoundException for TupleConverter

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way to write and register a `TupleConverter` converter in Spring Data? I'm getting this exception when I have an @Query annotation in the Repository interface and asking for Projection.

The Interface:

```
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, Integer> {
    @Query("select p.projectId, p.projectName, p.techstack from Project p")
    public List<ProjectItem> findAllForTest();
}
```

The DTO:

```
public class ProjectItem {
    private final Integer projectId;
    private final String projectName;
    private final String techstack;
    @JsonCreator
    public ProjectItem(
        @JsonProperty("projectId") Integer projectId, 
        @JsonProperty("projectName") String projectName, 
        @JsonProperty("techstack") String techstack
    ) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
        this.projectName = projectName;
        this.techstack = techstack;
    }
    public Integer getProjectId() {
        return projectId;
    }
    public String getProjectName() {
        return projectName;
    }
    public String getTechstack() {
        return techstack;
    }
}
```

The exception

> > No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [project.item.ProjectItem]] with root cause

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [JPQL Constructor Expression](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#Result_Classes_Constructor_Expressions_):

```
@Query("select new com.company.path.to.ProjectItem(p.projectId, p.projectName, p.techstack) from Project p")
```

Comment: This works even with the `Feign Client` though I have to specify the attributes which is not pretty.

Answer (score 2):

You're close. If you just want a DTO with a few of the items from the original item, just use the [interface projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.11.11.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections.interfaces) technique with methods having the same signatures as the `Project` class method items you want:

```
public interface ProjectTestSummary {
    public Integer getProjectId();
    public String getProjectName();
    public String getTechstack();
}
```

And in your DAO:

```
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, Integer> {
    public List<ProjectTestSummary> findAllProjectedBy();
}
```

Comment: This works until I try to use the `FeignClient` and then there is no way for Feign to decode the interface version. "feign.codec.DecodeException: Type definition error: [simple type, class project.item.ProjectSummary]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `project.item.ProjectSummary` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information" PS> Thanks for double answer!

Comment: Oh! Interesting use case. I would make clear what your trying to accomplish with Feign in your question, otherwise SO solutions will just  be tackling the projection issue in their answers.

Comment: But writing test case for this is difficult